# Where is the pun in 22 and "nyan"?

Tags: puns

Can someone please explain the pun? I don't see the relation between *22* and *nyan*.

猫【ねこ】の鳴【な】き声【ごえ】「ニャン」の語呂合【ごろあ】わせから「猫【ねこ】の日【ひ】」とされる2月【がつ】22日【にち】を前【まえ】に、調査【ちょうさ】結果【けっか】をまとめて公表【こうひょう】した

*The survey results were compiled and released in advance of February 22, which is "Cat Day," due to the Japanese word for the cat's meow, "nyan."*

https://mainichi.jp/articles/20230216/k00/00m/020/319000c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the following, the 'readings' of numbers are sometimes changed so that the readings mean something else. You can find more common mnemonic reading in [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AA%9E%E5%91%82%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B#%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E6%9A%97%E8%A8%98).

- [When (or how) were simplified numbers in Japanese used e.g. mi = 3, na = 7, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/101424)

In the case of 2/22, it is simply reading 2 as **に**ゃん, which starts with に. So, 2/22 is the longest possible consecutive 2's as a date, read にゃんにゃんにゃん which sounds like cats' meowing, hence Cat Day.

I just found that in 2022, there were even more 2's and it was called [スーパー猫の日](https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/national/20220215-OYT1T50229/).

---

According to [here](https://psnews.jp/cat/p/35942/#3-5)

- 11/1 is 犬の日 - reading 1 as わん is common (the English number 'one'). The pun is the same. Practically this is less recognized (less advertised marketing-wise).
- 11/22 is ペットたちに感謝する日 by わんわんにゃーにゃー. Also this date is commonly known as いい夫婦{ふうふ}の日 ('Good Couples Day', reading 1 as い and 2 as ふ(う)).

(BTW according to the same webpage, 8/8 is World Cat Day).

Comment: November is full of "good" days, some more... adult than others.